# Pass any struct member to function

Tags: c, function, pointers, struct

I have the following struct:

```
typedef struct
{
    uint8_t number;
    uint8_t user_bank;
    uint8_t temperature;
    float acc_xyz[3];
    float gyro_xyz[3];
    float mag_xyz[3];
    float acc_bias[3];
    float gyro_bias[3];
    float quaternions[4];
    char *orientation_of_IMU;
    char *component_orientation_on_pcb;
} Sensor;
```

I am interested in representing some of the float members as bytes, so i can transfer them through SPI. So far I have these functions, which allow me to wrap the 4 float quaternions, and return 16 bytes in the buffer.

```
typedef char byte;
void floatToByteArray(float f, byte buf[4])
{
    memcpy(buf, &f, sizeof(f));
}

//Function that takes float quaternions from a sensor struct, and returns their values, represented as bytes for easier SPI transfer.

void wrap_quaternions(Sensor* imu, int8_t *buff)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        floatToByteArray(imu->quaternions[i], &buff[4*i]);
    }
}
```

Now I am interested in generalizing it, so I can take any of my float array members in the Sensor struct, and wrap these accordingly. I would love to be able to call the floatToByteArray function with an argument being imu->float_member but i can't do that. Then i could change the number 4 to be sizeof(float_member).

Is there a workaround for this ?

Comment: Replace the `Sensor* imu` argument with `int cnt, float *arr[cnt]`.  Then you can pass for example `3, sensor->gyro_bias`, or you could pass `sizeof(sensor->gyro_bias)/sizeof(float), sensor->gyro_bias`.

Comment: Awesome! I'll add that in, and create a nested struct in my sensor struct for wrapped data. Then i'll use arguments `sizeof(sensor->acc_bias), sensor ->acc_bias, sensor -> wrapped_data -> acc_bias_wrapped` . That should work, right?

Comment: Hmm. I tried it, but it doesn't seem to work. Maybe you can check my other comment?

Comment: Oops, sorry, I messed up my example.  `float *arr[cnt]` should be just `float arr[cnt]` in the argument list.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use your float parameter as a pointer? Pointers are very handy for the situations like this.

Answer (score 0):

I tried implementing Toms idea, but i still seem to get an error, as the program doesn't behave as it should. Maybe one of you can help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
 
typedef char byte;
void floatToByteArray(float f, byte buf[4])
{
    memcpy(buf, &f, sizeof(f));
}
 
 void wrap_floatData(int cnt, float *arr[cnt], int8_t *buff)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++)
    {
        floatToByteArray(*arr[i], &buff[cnt*i]);

    }
}


struct Sensor_Data_Wrapped
{
    int8_t quaternions_wrapped[16];
    int8_t mag_xyz_wrapped[12];
    int8_t acc_bias_wrapped[12];
    int8_t gyro_bias_wrapped[12];
};

typedef struct
{
    uint8_t number;
    uint8_t user_bank;
    uint8_t temperature;
    float acc_xyz[3];
    float gyro_xyz[3];
    float mag_xyz[3];
    float acc_bias[3];
    float gyro_bias[3];
    float quaternions[4];
    char *orientation_of_IMU;
    char *component_orientation_on_pcb;
    //struct Sensor_Data_Wrapped wrapped_data;
} Sensor;


Sensor IMU1;
Sensor IMU2; 
int8_t Wrapped_IMU1_bias[12];
 
int main(void) 
{
    
    Wrapped_IMU1_bias[1] = 25;
    
    IMU1.gyro_bias[0] =119.0;
    IMU1.gyro_bias[1] = 1349;
    IMU1.gyro_bias[2] = 5.2;


    
    wrap_floatData(3, IMU1.gyro_bias, Wrapped_IMU1_bias);

    
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
                printf("Byte is %d", Wrapped_IMU1_bias[i]);
                printf("\n");

    }

return 0; 
    
}
```

Errors are:

main.c:89:20: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘wrap_floatData’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
main.c:39:7: note: expected ‘float **’ but argument is of type ‘float *’ Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: Oops, sorry, I messed up my example.  `float *arr[cnt]` should be just `float arr[cnt]` in the argument list.

Comment: Nice. It's all good now. I see that the sizeof function gives me 12, since the arrays consist of 3 floats (12 bytes). I've defined my own N_elements function `N_ELEMS(x)  (sizeof(x) / sizeof((x)[0]))` which gives me the desired outcome. Thanks for the help!